# reset the star-rating component, VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using star-rating plugin in vue js, and I am using v-model to show the ratings from db. Everything works fine as when user is not logged in and he/she tries to rate it shows an error "login to rate", but the stars dont reset to db value instead it shows the rating of not logged in user. Currently after the error msg I am refreshing the whole page. Is there a simple way to reset the stars instead of refreshing the whole page?

```
 :show-rating="false" @rating-selected="setRating" v-model="rating"
                         v-bind:star-size="20"
```

above is the start rating and while clicking it calls a function where I am checking if user is logged in or not with an api call. Thanks in advance.

```
        setRating: function (rating) {

            axios.get('/checkuser').then(response => {

                this.user = response.data;

                if (this.user === "Logout") {
                    toastr.error('Please login to rate', 'Error', {
                        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
                    });
                    window.location = "/menu/" + this.menu_id;
                } else {
                    // save in to db
                }

            }).catch(error => {

                // TODO: Handle error
            });

        },
```

Comment: Did you check added answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fix it by using "this.load()" after the api call, which refreshes all components. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reset `rating` object if it's not logged in.

```
setRating: function (rating) {

    axios.get('/checkuser').then(response => {
        ...
        if (this.user === "Logout") {
            ...
            this.rating = 0; <=== reset rating here (in data, not the rating parameter)
        }
        ...
    })
    ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to fix it by using "this.load()" after the api call, which refreshes all components. :)

Comment: @HashaamAhmed OK, but I guess you should avoid `load` if you are doing it only for ratings.

Comment: Oh, why is that so? Explain please as m new in vue js :)

Comment: @HashaamAhmed as you mentioned "which refreshes all components" meaning there would be extra render cycle for every component though you only want to refresh ratings.

Comment: alright, thanks. I will see if really effects my page due to this.load
:)